# Long mysql insert queries

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a limit to how long these should/can be?

I currently have an insert query

```
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO cards (user_id, deck_id,card_one,card_two,card_three,card_order,temp_id) VALUES";
```

Values

```
$insert_sql .= "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";//int,int,text,text,text,int,int
```

The texts have a max value of 5,000 characters.

There can be anywhere from 1 to 1,000 of the above insert values

Is it better to break this up into seperate queries?

example:

```
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO cards (user_id, 
deck_id,card_one,card_two,card_three,card_order,temp_id) VALUES   
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
This last part here ^ can have between 1-1000 sets of question marks
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html):

> Although InnoDB supports row sizes larger than 65,535 bytes internally, MySQL itself imposes a row-size limit of 65,535 for the combined size of all columns

Assuming you have 8 columns each of which contained 5000 characters, then the smallest amount of memory this would require would be 40KB, assuming only 1 byte per character (and it could more than this depending on the encoding you use).  However, you could also exceed the limit imposed by MySQL.

I view your problem as being more of a design issue, specifically you are trying to cram too much data into a single record.  You may consider changing your design by giving a single column or subset of columns their own separate table.

With regard to your `INSERT` statements, there is nothing wrong with doing a bulk `INSERT`.  The only risk in doing 1000 inserts at once, with each record containing a potentially large amount of data, is that you could lock the MySQL database engine, preventing anything else from using it.  In this case, you can consider breaking up the `INSERT` statements into small batches, and spacing out when you insert each batch.

Comment: by 1,000 values, I mean 1,000 rows. There's only 8 columns in the table. Also, design wise, do you mean I should give each of those text columns their own table?